# Ruby hosting for Sinatra + Apache Solr multicore + SQL DB

Tags: ruby, solr, web-hosting

I'm totally new to the Ruby world and I'm wondering if there are hosting companies around where I could run a Ruby app powered by Sinatra and run a Tomcat server where I could deploy a Solr instance.

I guess I probably have to look for a dedicated server or housing solution. Notice it's not for business, just for fun - at least so far ;)

Anyway, is it possible to use a pluging for ruby (not Rails) who can support multi-core configuration for Solr? Do hosting companies give support for these plugins?

Answer (score 0):

For hosting, I would say anything should do. VPS or dedicated. I think there's a Heroku plugin for Solr, but I'm not sure.

As for a plugin, [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) is compatible with Sinatra.